# Rails - single user to update the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am creating my first every Rails site and I started using the Devise gem to create a login for myself, so I can add content (for example I want to add a new movie review).

Since I am the only one using the site - how do I hide and disable the sign_up URL so that no one else can sign up?

Do I just keep the "/users/sign_in" URL hidden so that only I know it? 
How do I prevent anyone else from signing up?

Is there a better way to do this without using devise?

Many Thanks

Comment: Well, to me using devise to handle backend sign-up is an overkill as you don't need 99% of its features. Just use `has_secure_password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `:registerable` from the model.

So

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

becomes

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Comment: Worth noting that you should only do this AFTER you have added yourself as a user in production. Or you can still add yourself as a user through Rails console whenever.

Comment: ok so I still login using the 'hidden' URL /users/sign_in?  Also it errors when I try to sign out?

Comment: ya. you will still be able to login using that url. what is the error when you logout?

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Comment: Did you change your routes.rb file at all? Put the ```:registerable``` module back. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: I put :registerable back but same error, I didn't change the routes file. Is it anything to to with a missing destroy path:  <li>  <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "active"  %></li>

Comment: cant seem to find: destroy_user_session_path?

Comment: Go ahead and remove the ```:registerable``` module again. Was just making sure my advice didn't cause the error. It has to be an issue with your routes.rb file. Can you post it?

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :movies


  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'movies#index'


end